# Jawr + Spring - Images not found. Am I missing something?

Tags: spring, jawr

I'm trying to integrate Jawr into my Spring application:

```
  <bean abstract="true" id="jawrBase" class="net.jawr.web.servlet.JawrSpringController">
    <property name="configuration">
      <props>
        <prop key="jawr.debug.on">false</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.gzip.on">true</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.js.bundle.all.id">/static/all.js</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.js.bundle.all.mappings">/static/js/**</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.css.bundle.basedir">/static/css</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.css.factory.use.singlebundle">true</prop>
        <prop key="jawr.css.factory.singlebundle.bundlename">/static/all.css</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jawrJsController" parent="jawrBase" />

  <bean id="jawrCSSController" parent="jawrBase">
    <property name="type" value="css" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
      <props>
        <prop key="/**/*.js">jawrJsController</prop>
        <prop key="/**/*.css">jawrCSSController</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

My folder structure:

- static

  - images
  - css
  - js

CSS and JS files are properly mapped to all.css/all.js.
But Images can't be found.

Snippet from my /static/css/style.css:

```
header,
footer
{
  background-image: url( ../images/sprite.png );
  color: #fff;
}
```

This will be changed in /test/gzip_954035349/static/all.css to:

```
header, footer{background-image:url(../../static/images/sprite.png);color:#fff;}
```

Which should be the correct behavior, because this would result in an absolute path to `/test/static/images/sprite.png`

There's another image in this folder called favicon.png which I can access by `http://localhost:8080/test/static/images/favicon.png`
Therefor I should be able to also access my sprite with `http://localhost:8080/test/static/images/sprite.png` which causes an Stackoverflow Exception...

Comment: Where is the `static` folder located on your server, in relation to `WEB-INF` directory?

Comment: @Ralph in the same directory, so it's public to anyone.

Comment: fixed, see edit for more information.

Comment: if you write the fix as an answer, the question can be finished (answer accepted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed...

I've added `<mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/static/**" />`

to my `dispatcher-servlet.xml`