# Spring 3 -- images not appearing in JSP

Tags: image, spring

This is probably some simple little thing I'm doing wrong, but I'll ask anyway.  I have several images that aren't showing up in my JSP.  My images are stored at WEB-INF/pages/images.  Here is a sample of how I'm referring to them in my JSP.

```
<img src="images/guestbook.jpg" alt="Guest Book" />
```

I'm also getting this error in my console.

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ghs1986/images/guestbook.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'ghs1986'
```

Comment: your answer may be here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215014/jawr-spring-images-not-found-am-i-missing-something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your spring-config.xml, add:

```
<mvc:resources location="/images/" mapping="/images/**" />
```

Comment: This removed the warning, but there are still no images in my browser screen.

Comment: I changed the location to WEB-INF/pages/images/, and that was what finally worked.  Thanks to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your image folder path & try using application context while pointing to your images. 
Try using ${pageContext.request.contextPath}.

for e.g

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/images/guestbook.jpg" alt="Guest Book" />
```

Change this as per your path / needs.